# React Native Nativebase how to float Picker to the right

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, native-base

I have arrow down button that I want to float the right side.

```
<Form>
                    <Item inlineLabel>
                        <Label>Name *</Label>
                        <Input
                            autoFocus
                            type="text"
                            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ name: text })}
                            value={this._replaceSpace(this.state.name)}
                            placeholderTextColor="#BFC6EA"
                            placeholder='Grilled Chicken'
                            style={{ textAlign: 'right', marginRight: 10 }}
                        />
                    </Item>
                    <Item inlineLabel>
                        <Label>Serving Per Container *</Label>
                        
                            <Picker
                                mode="dropdown"
                                iosHeader="Select your SIM"
                                iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" style={{}} />}
                                style={{ width: undefined }}
                                selectedValue={this.state.selected}
                                onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
                            >
                                <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
                                <Picker.Item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
                                <Picker.Item label="Debit Card" value="key2" />
                                <Picker.Item label="Credit Card" value="key3" />
                                <Picker.Item label="Net Banking" value="key4" />
                            </Picker>
                        
                    </Item>
                </Form>
```

[image: Image code]

Comment: You have any expo link where I can try?

Comment: for the Picker: `flex: 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody encounters this problem. `flex: 1` to the label component.